# In Python 3.8, how do I load image data from a file for inclusion ina JSON object?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file, getimagedata

I'm using Python 3.8.  I want to get image byte data into a JSON object.  So I tried this

```
with open(os.path.join(dir_path, "../image_data", "myimg.jpg"), mode='rb') as img_file:
    image_data = img_file.read().decode("utf-16")
    my_json_data = {
        "image_data": image_data
        ...
    }
```

but the `image_data =` line is giving this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: illegal UTF-16 surrogate
```

What's the proper way to load data for inclusion into a JSON object?

Comment: Probably because the image you're reading isn't encoded as utf-16?

Comment: Image data is usually binary (as appropriately handled by ``mode='rb'``). Why do you assume it is utf-16?

Comment: How are you planning to encode it for the json file - since JSON is text only don;t you need to encode it using base64 or similar ?

Answer (score 0):

`decode` and `encode` work on character data.  You use them to covert between character encoding formats, such as utf-8 and ASCII.  It doesn't make sense to take pure binary data -- such as an image -- and try to convert it to characters.  Not every binary value can be converted to character; most character formats leave a few values as reserved or unused.

What you need is a simple raw byte format.  Read the file as a sequence of bytes; this preserves the binary form, making it easy for your eventual JSON consumer to utilize the information.